# html php javascript form popup

Tags: php, javascript, forms, popup

Apologies for the ambiguous title, it just goes to show how confused I am with this one.

```
<a href"page.php?article_id=123&&img_id=img1">change image</a>
```

The link above is inside a form and is supposed to allow a user to change the image on an article. The functional php side of things is sorted - uploading the image, changing the image etc, but this will require the main form being submitted which is fine for the initial upload - not so much for the edit.

When the user clicks the "change image" link, I would ideally like to process that particular request alone in a different form, then update the parent page. I thought of doing it with a javascript new window popup which would have been ideal, except that I can't figure out how to pass the `article_id` as well as the `img_id` to the new popup page but above all... is this the most efficient way of doing this nowadays?

If not, How do I carry out this task? I have thought of ajax, jquery... but the same issue of passing the `article_id` and `img_id` still limits me.

I hope all of this makes sense and thanks in advance

ps: An article can have multiple images and article id is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why cant u receive article_id and img_id?

if you use:

```
<a href"#" onclick="window.open('page.php?article_id=123&&img_id=img1', 'window1');">edit</a>
```

u can get article_id and img_id in $_GET

however, this is a oldfashioned way getting this done.

Comment: This opens new tab instead of a popup window and if I create a popup window, most users have popups blocked. any way around it? I really like the ajax modal popup, but don't know enough about it to implement it whilst passing php variables to it. Any ideas or or a nudge in the right direction will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: the browser takes control of popups. he decides whether it is a new tab or a popup window

Answer (score 1):

ajax sounds good to me.
may be you try something like this (jquery)?!

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "page.php",
  data: { article_id: 123, images: { i1: "img1", i2: "img2" } }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "done: " + msg );
});
```

for further information and examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: can I have a dynamic article id with this?

Comment: do you mean something like:

`data: { article_id: article_var, images: { i1: "img1", i2: "img2" } }`

Answer (score 0):

Check this up: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ - jQuery is a prerequisite but plugin allows you to send form elements via ajax, including file fields using simple API and does all heavy lifting for you.